# How to set partial view with submit form to all my main view in MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

> **Note:** My complete below code is working.
>
> I want to add my partial view (`_Login.cshtml`), to display on all my views(`about.cshtml`, `contact.cshtml`, `product.cshtml`, etc..)
>
> My question is, how can I achieve it?. Because, my partial view (`_Login.cshtml`)has a header tag with model name( this model belongs to `Index.cshtml`) like below

```
@using TestProject.Models
@model ViewSignInAndSignUp // this model refers only Index.cshtml
```

> so, what will be my header `@model` tag, if i need to add this partial view to another main views(`about.cshtml`, `contact.cshtml`, `product.cshtml`, etc..)

I have a view called `_Login.cshtml`(Partial view)
Right now it is linked with `Index.cshtml`(Main view)

**_Login.cshtml**(Partial View)

```
@using TestProject.Models
@model ViewSignInAndSignUp 
@using (Html.BeginForm("ControllerSignIn", "Home"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(si => si.getSignin.userName, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtLogin" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(si => si.getSignin.password, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtPassword", @type = "password" })
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-rounded" value="Login" id="btnLoginSubmit" />
}
```

**Model**

```
public class ViewSignInAndSignUp 
{
    public SignIn getSignin { get; set; }
    public ModelIndex ModelIndex{ get; set; }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**(Main View)

```
@using TestProject.Models
@model ViewSignInAndSignUp 

@using (Html.BeginForm("ControllerSignIn", "Home"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(si => si.ModelIndex.Par1, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtPar1" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(si => si.ModelIndex.Par1, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtPar1" })
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-rounded" value="Submit" id="btnModelIndex" />
}

@Html.Partial("_Login")   //partialview
```

**HomeController**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ControllerSignIn()
{
    // some coding
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

> so how can I add my partial view to all rest of my views(`about.cshtml`, `contact.cshtml`, `product.cshtml`, etc..)

Answer (score 0):

You can alter your model structure in order to achieve that more easily. Let's say you have a ModelBase that ModelIndex, ModelContact etc. extends. ModelBase also has ViewSignInAndSignUp as property. That way, you can add the partial view wherever you want if you extend your class to ModelBase. Would be better if you put it in a MasterLayout if all pages will include it.

```
public class ModelBase
{
    public ViewSignInAndSignUp ViewSignInAndSignUp { get; set; }
}

public class ModelIndex : ModelBase
{
    //ModelIndex properties
}
```

Then, in your View you can use like:

```
@Html.Partial("_Login", Model.ViewSignInAndSignUp)
```

Better practice is using this @Html.Partial once in MasterLayout instead of all particular views.